# What Event should I use (clearly not MouseEvent) [I'm super new to as3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, mouseevent

I've searched for this but I think the answer is so basic I can't find it (i've been doing flash for 5 days)

I have a bunch of objects and when one is clicked my items go up, and any time the items >= 1, I want a different object (clover) to glow.

I am doing this with a MouseEvent, but I can't get the clover to glow unless I click on the object...so Clearly MouseEvent.CLICK is not what I want. I just want the object to glow once my items >=1. Code below (i've edited it for brevity so I may have left something out, but I get no errors when I run it)

```
//import greensock
import com.greensock.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//make a variable to count items
var items = 0;

//add a click event to the clover
clover.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, payUp); //this is where i think it's wrong...

//click on b1 merch item
merch.b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, grabB1)

function grabB1(e: MouseEvent): void {
 //make the item disappear and add 1 to items
merch.b1.visible = false;
items++
merch.b1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, grabB1)
}

//explain the payUp function
function payUp(m:MouseEvent){
if (items >= 1) {
    //make the clover glow green
    TweenMax.to(clover, 0.5, {glowFilter:{color:0x66CC00, alpha:1, blurX:40, blurY:40}});
    clover.buttonMode = true;
    clover.useHandCursor = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: IT's not clear what the problem is?  Nothing happens when you click one of your items?   Where are your items in the code?   is that what `merch.b1`?  Seems like all you need to do is call `payUp()` in your `grabB1` function, since you don't want the user to click the clover right?

Comment: yep i want to click `merch.b1` and have clover glow. Right now when I click merch.b1, clover only glows once I click on it. If I click on clover before clicking on merch.b1, it won't glow (which is correct)(I also have a 'merch.b2', 'merch.b3' etc, but I left those out of this code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a bunch of items (only 1 shown in your code to keep it simple? merch.b1?).  When any of those items are clicked, you want to make the `clover` glow if your `items` var is greater or equal to `1`.

If I have that right, then this should answer your question (with some tips thrown in to reduce redundant code).

```
//add a click event to the clover
clover.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cloverClick);
//disable the ability to click the clover at first
clover.mouseEnalbled = false;
clover.mouseChildren = false;

//click listeners for your items
merch.b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClick);

function itemClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //make the item disappear

    var itemClicked:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
    //e.currentTarget is a reference to the item clicked
    //so you can have just this one handler for all the items mouse clicks

    itemClicked.visible = false;

    //if you want the item to be garbage collect (totally gone), you also need to remove it from the display (instead of just making it invisible)
    itemClicked.parent.removeChild(itemClicked);

    items++
    itemClicked.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClick);

    //now see if the clover needs to grow
    playUp();
}

//explain the payUp function
function payUp(){
    if (items >= 1) {
        //make the clover glow green
        TweenMax.to(clover, 0.5, {glowFilter:{color:0x66CC00, alpha:1, blurX:40, blurY:40}});

        //make the clover clickable
        clover.buttonMode = true;
        clover.useHandCursor = true;
        clover.mouseEnalbled = true;
        clover.mouseChildren = true;
    }
}

function cloverClick(e:Event):void {
    //do whatever you need to do when the clover is clicked
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! Thanks also for the advice on the rest of the code!